# can't retrieve save object from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I create an object like this :

```
var TodoItem = mongoose.model('TodoItem',
new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String
}));


var n = new TodoItem();
n.description = req.body.description;
n.title = req.body.title;
n.done = false;
n.save(function (err, todoitem) {

     //todoitem._id does not work, I have to do todoitem._doc._id
}
```

Why can't I access the save object directly on todoitem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when mongoose returns object it have some other enriched properties with it.Either use options toJSON/toObject while creating the schema or use below code:

**Answer 1**

```
var omitPrivate = function(doc, item) {
    delete item.id;
    delete item.__v;
    return item;
};

// options
var options = {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: omitPrivate
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: omitPrivate
    }
};
    var TodoItem = mongoose.model('TodoItem',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        description: String
    },options));

var n = new TodoItem();

    n.description = req.body.description;
    n.title = req.body.title;
    n.done = false;
    n.save(function (err, todoitem) {
    console.log(todoitem.toJSON());     

})
```

**Answer 2**

```
  var n = new TodoItem();
        n.description = req.body.description;
        n.title = req.body.title;
        n.done = false;
        n.save(function (err, todoitem) {
        todoitem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(todoitem));
        console.log(todoitem._id);

        })
```

Comment: answer 2 works :)  Answer 1 looks like a lot of plumbing code to write but probably better on the long run. I will give it a go. Thanks !